# The beginning place of love

Tags: word-choice

How do you express "the beginning place of love?"

> Here, we start to love.
>   Here, we start out our love.

Comment: @user3780  Can you add a little more context?  Is this for a conversational use, a poem, an academic paper, an email, etc.?  (We'll happily supply expressions, regardless, but it will get you a better answer if you add more specificity.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is: "to get (romantically) involved". **To fall in love** is also a classic.

Comment: yes, fall in love

Answer (score 4):

A few options:

- Love at first sight
- Beginning of our relationship
- Became more than friends
- Things became serious
- This is when I knew I loved you
- Where we first met/kissed/touched

I am also fond of F'x's classic: This is where we fell in love.

Answer (score 3):

"This is where our love began to flower."

Comment: Or also: “blossom” or “flourish”…